# Building dynamic queries in Laravel - how to do a multiple option search

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, method-chaining

So I am trying to set up a search page and it has multiple get options But I am curious as to how to set this up correctly, I know this is far from correct as I am doing if statements inside of setting a variable, But I am so lost right now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public function index()
{

    $queryUsername = Request::get('u');
    $queryPostcode = Request::get('p');
    $queryOrderbyPhotos = Request::get('o1');
    $queryOrderbyOnline = Request::get('o2');
    $queryOrderbyTypes = Request::get('o3');

    $users = User::rightJoin('user_profiles','users.id', '=', 'user_profiles.user_id')

    if ($queryUsername) 
    {
        ->where('users.username', '=', "$queryUsername")
    }
    if ($queryPostcode) {   
        ->where('user_profiles.postcode', '=', "$queryPostcode")
    }
    if ($queryOrderbyPhotos) {  
        ->whereNotNull('user_profile.avatar')
    }
    if ($queryOrderbyOnline) {  
        ->orderBy('users.last_online', 'DESC')
    }
    if ($queryOrderbyType) {    
        ->orderBy('users.type', 'DESC')
    }
    ->get();

    return view('view', compact('users'));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I'll approach the problem. I'll create a variable holding the query builder and then call all the additional query methods on it.

With Eloquent and actually with any class that allows [Method Chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining#PHP) you can do this:

```
$query = User::select(...)->join(..);
$query->where(...);
$query->get(...);
```

So in your case I'll be trying to achieve what you want in this manner:

```
   public function index()
    {
        $input = Request::all();

        $query = User::rightJoin('user_profiles', 'users.id', '=', 'user_profiles.user_id');

        if (isset($input['u']) && $input['u'])
            $query->where('users.username', '=', $input['u']);

        if (isset($input['p'])  && $input['p'])
            $query->where('user_profiles.postcode', '=', $input ['p']);

        if (isset($input['o1']) && $input['o1'])
            $query->whereNotNull('user_profile.avatar');

        if (isset($input['o2']) && $input['o2'])
            $query->orderBy('users.last_online', 'DESC');

        if (isset($input ['o3']) && $input['o3'])
            $query->orderBy('users.type', 'DESC');

        $users = $query->get();

        return view('view', compact('users'));
    }
```

*Of course it will be a good idea that you have an additional check for valid input on each input parameter. But this can be achieved in many ways. You can read more about [Laravel Controller Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#controller-validation)* or [Laravel Form Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#form-request-validation)

*By the way I'll suggest to move all this code in your model or in separate class as I prefer keeping controllers slim.*

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, Yeah I was actually looking into the validation to stop sql attacks!.

Comment: sorry I gave you a wrong link. If you are using Laravel 5.1+ I'll suggest using Form request validation to keep the complex validation rules separate: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#form-request-validation

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
$users_query = new User;
$users_query->rightJoin(....);

if ($queryUsername)
{
    $users_query->where('users.username', '=', "$queryUsername")
}
// Your other conditions .....
....

$users = $users_query->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

**multiple option search**

This is a trait that can be used by any models

**This function will remove code repetitions into your project**

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $keyword, $columns = [], $relativeTables = [])
{
    if (empty($columns)) {
        $columns = array_except(
            Schema::getColumnListing($this->table), $this->guarded
        );
    }   

    $query->where(function ($query) use ($keyword, $columns) {
        foreach ($columns as $key => $column) {
            $clause = $key == 0 ? 'where' : 'orWhere';
            $query->$clause($column, "LIKE", "%$keyword%");

            if (!empty($relativeTables)) {
                $this->filterByRelationship($query, $keyword, $relativeTables);
            }
        }
    });

    return $query;
}
```

**Filter into relationship also**

```
private function filterByRelationship($query, $keyword, $relativeTables)
{
    foreach ($relativeTables as $relationship => $relativeColumns) {
        $query->orWhereHas($relationship, function($relationQuery) use ($keyword, $relativeColumns) {
            foreach ($relativeColumns as $key => $column) {
                $clause = $key == 0 ? 'where' : 'orWhere';
                $relationQuery->$clause($column, "LIKE", "%$keyword%");
            }
        });
    }

    return $query;
}
```