# How to use regex or any other operator with whereIn clause

Tags: laravel, mongodb, eloquent, orm, laravel-8

Is there any way we can use operator or regex as we normally do with the whereIn() clause.

I want to use something like this

`$query->whereIN(name,'like','%test%');`

I'm getting multiple data in an array. It should return data if name contains any of the keywords.

For eg. $searchArray = ['test','case'];
So it should return data with name containing values in $searchArray

Is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [laravel querybuilder how to use like in wherein function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34329886/laravel-querybuilder-how-to-use-like-in-wherein-function)

Answer (score 0):

The whereIn method verifies that a given column's value is contained within the given array:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                    ->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])
                    ->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses

Try this:

```
where('title', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%')
```

UPDATE:

```
  $query->where(function ($query) use ($keyword, $columns) {
       foreach ($columns as $key => $column) {
          $clause = $key == 0 ? 'where' : 'orWhere';
          $query->$clause($column, "LIKE", "%$keyword%");
          if (!empty($relativeTables)) {
              $this->filterByRelationship($query, $keyword, 
          $relativeTables);
          }
      }
   });
```

Comment: I have to search multiple keyword. I have edited the question

Comment: You should build a dynamic query
check here:
https://j8n.medium.com/laravel-how-to-create-a-dynamic-query-in-laravel-96d6da16dbc6

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36216819/building-dynamic-queries-in-laravel-how-to-do-a-multiple-option-search

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same problem. The only way i was able do solve, was with mongodb native query aggregation. Let me show how i did.

I made a function to use in all of my system

```
 public function matchLikeIn($match, $field, $value,$option = 'i')
{
    try {
        $or = array();
        foreach($value as $v){
            $or['$or'][] = [
                $field => [
                    '$regex' => $v,
                    '$options' => $option
                ]
            ];
        }
        $match['$and'][] = $or;
        return $match;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
       
    }
}
```

A exemple using it

```
    $match = array();
    $names = ["name1","name2"];
    $match = $this->matchLikeIn($match, "name", $names, 'i');
    $aggregate[] = ['$match' => $match];
    $query = Model::raw(function ($collection) use ($aggregate) {
        return $collection->aggregate($aggregate);
    })->toArray();
```